# Why window.history.pushState updates my content but not the URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, history

I want to be able to switch the language on my client-only React app without page reload. I was able to achieve that, but my url is not changing as it was before.

I have 2 languages - **French** - `/fr`, **English** - `/en`

This is the URL language method I tried with `window.history.pushState`

```
function generateUrlSwitch(lang) {
    const location = window.location.pathname;
    if (location.length > 3) {
        const actualPath = location.substr(4, location.length);
        const url = `/${lang}/${actualPath}`;
         return window.history.pushState(null, null, url);
    } else {
        return '/' + lang;
    }
}
```

**Current Behaviour:**

Content update to chosen language without reload - url stays the same, but I can see the parameter is switching in milliseconds between en/fr and also when I console.log both options are in console.

**Expected Behaviour:**

Content updated based on chosen language without page reload + url update based on chosen language

Language Switcher is just calling the function:

```
  href={generateUrlSwitch('en')}
  href={generateUrlSwitch('fr')}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: [`replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState) does not return anything. Nor does [`pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState).

Comment: I tried to return there `lang`, but the output was the same without any change.